# How do I over ride (new class) a facade in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-facade

I've get the following class

```
<?php

namespace App;


class Currency extends \Casinelli\Currency\Currency
{

    /**
     * Create a new instance.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Foundation\Application $app
     */
    public function __construct($app)
    {
        parent::__construct($app);
        $this->setCurrency(getCurrency());
    }
}
```

I've replaced the 'aliases' in `app.php`:

```
   - 'Currency' => \Casinelli\Currency\Facades\Currency::class,
   + 'Currency' => \App\Currency::class,
```

However, I'm running into an error of:

`Non-static method Casinelli\Currency\Currency::rounded() should not be called statically`

It seems my `Currency` class is not being treated as a `Facade`... How would I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

Before answering, I recommend to **fork** the package, do your modifications and use your fork. Because if something change in the package, your override may not work anymore.

> Let's take a look at the package.

You have 3 important files :

The currency that you want to extend:
https://github.com/Casinelli/Currency/blob/master/src/Casinelli/Currency/Currency.php

The facade that you want to use : 
https://github.com/Casinelli/Currency/blob/master/src/Casinelli/Currency/Facades/Currency.php

And finally, the ServiceProvider that register the class you want to extends:
https://github.com/Casinelli/Currency/blob/master/src/Casinelli/Currency/CurrencyServiceProvider.php#L60

The service provider will register the `class` Currency as a singleton with the alias of `currency`

Then, when you call the `facade` Currency, it will look for the alias `currency` and return a the instance of the `class` Currency.

> Implement your own Currency

To use your own Currency `class`, you will need to register your own implementation of the Currency `class` in a service provider that will replace the service provider of the package.

1. Create your own serviceProvider
   `$ php artisan make:provider ExtendedCurrencyServiceProvider`
2. In your file `app/config/app.php`,
   Replace `Casinelli\Currency\CurrencyServiceProvider::class,`
   with `App\Providers\ExtendedCurrencyServiceProvider::class,`
3. In your new service provider change to this

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Casinelli\Currency\CurrencyServiceProvider;

class ExtendedCurrencyServiceProvider extends CurrencyServiceProvider
{
     /**
     * Register currency provider.
     */
    public function registerCurrency()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('currency', function ($app) {
            return new App\Yournamespace\CurrencyClass($app);
        });
    }
}
```

4. **Laravel 5.5+** *In your `composer.json` remove the service provider from the autodiscovery*

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
            "Casinelli\\Currency\\CurrencyServiceProvider"
        ]
    }
},
```

Now, when you will call `\Currency::rounded()` it will call your own implementation of the currency.

You don't need to change the Facade.

Comment: Apologies I forgot to mention I already added a "CurrencyServiceProvider", as described in your answer. It still runs into that same error.

It does not seem to be executing the lamda function within `registerCurrency`.

Comment: But you're using the `Facade` as follow : `'Currency' => \Casinelli\Currency\Facades\Currency::class,` and your `CurrencyServiceProvider` register correctly your Currency `Class` as I demonstrated, right ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message / exception is very misleading...

The issue was due to calling `App\Currency::rounded` instead of: `Casinelli\Currency\Facades\Currency::rounded`...

Comment: Since it's a Facade, as I said on my post, you can also call `\Currency::rounded()`

Comment: With `'Currency' => \Casinelli\Currency\Facades\Currency::class`this facade registered in your `app.php` ?